# Removing items from a map based on the contents of another map

Tags: clojure

Still working through Programming Collective Intelligence and using Clojure to write the code. I've got it working, but some parts are really ugly, so I thought I'd ask some of the experts around here to help clean it up.

Let's suppose I have a map that looks like this (bound to "**recs**"):

```
{"Superman Returns" 3.902419556891574, "Lady in the Water" 2.8325499182641614, 
"Snakes on a Plane" 3.7059737842895792, "The Night Listener" 3.3477895267131017,
"You, Me and Dupree" 2.651006036204627, "Just My Luck" 2.5309807037655645}
```

and I want to remove those items with keys that are also in the map (bound to "**mymovies**"):

```
{"Snakes on a Plane" 4.5, "You, Me and Dupree" 1.0, "Superman Returns" 4.0}
```

so that I get the map:

```
{"Lady in the Water" 2.8325499182641614, "The Night Listener" 3.3477895267131017,
"Just My Luck" 2.5309807037655645}
```

the code that I managed to get to do this looks like:

```
(apply merge (map #(hash-map (first %) (second %))
              (remove #(contains? mymovies (first %))
                      recs)))
```

That seems pretty ugly to me. It doesn't seem like it should be necessary to create a map from the value I get back from "remove". Is there a cleaner way to do this?

UPDATE: Joost's answer below sparked another idea. If I turn the keys of the two maps into sets I can use *select-keys* like this:

```
(select-keys recs (difference (set (keys recs))
                              (set (keys mymovies))))
```

Joost, thanks for turning me on to *select-keys*. I didn't know about that function before. Now to go rewrite several other sections with this new found knowledge!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(apply dissoc recs (keys mymovies))
```

Comment: Nice! Not sure how I missed that function. So many functions to learn and remember...

Answer (score 2):

The following first builds a seq of keys to keep, then extracts the "submap" for those keys from recs using select-keys. It also takes advantage of the fact that sets are predicates.

```
(select-keys recs (remove (apply hash-set (keys mymovies)) (keys recs)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ponzao's answer is best for this case, but I wouldn't have thought to apply `dissoc`. Here are the two solutions I might have come up with: hopefully looking over them will help with similar future problems.

Note that the second solution will fail if your `mymovies` map contains nil or false values.

```
(into {}
      (for [[k v] recs
            :when (not (contains? mymovies k))]
        [k v]))

(into {}
      (remove (comp mymovies key) recs))
```